# Console displaying that 'PFFile has been saved' however there is no class in the parse database

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

This is my first time using parse and I am using back4app.com as a hosting service.  In my dashboard there is no new data besides the default TestObject.  My code to Upload the PFFile is below, is there anything I may be doing wrong as client side the code appears to work.

```
func Upload() {

    print(path)
    var videodata: NSData
    videodata = (NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path!) as? NSData)!

    let file = PFFile(name:"resume", data:videodata)

   file!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in print("File has been saved")
}

}
```

Comment: You haven't checked if you are getting success or error in your completion block before printing log.Check if it is giving error.

Comment: PFFiles aren't saved in the database. They are just saved in a storage bucket. You need to save the PFFile reference in an object yourself.

Comment: @Paulw11 Where is the storage bucket or how can I convert a PFFile to an object?

Comment: You need to assign the PFFile to a column of type PFFile in a parse object you create

Comment: @Paulw11 would you possibly give an example below I am new to the whole API framework

Comment: see https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#files ...